# A simple cyrcle moving with accelerometer

Tags: android, android-canvas, accelerometer, sensors

I have re-edited the whole topic again, based on what i have so far, since i had so many views on the previous topic and no replys. In the meanwhile i kinda figured out how accelerometer works. 

Now I have a cyrcle (canvas) which i would like to call "Zoga", if you don't mind. This cyrcle should move based on the angle of the phone. So basicly if the phone is moved on the left side, the cyrcle travels on the left side, if the phone is moved on down-right side, the cyrcle moves in that direction.

The cyrcle is created trough the class Zoga.java, and the whole magic heppens in GravitacijaActivity.java.

Here are 2 issues i have:

1.) **The cyrcle only moves in left dirrection.**

2.) **The cyrcle travels outside of the screen** (on the left side ofcourse)**.**

Any ideas on how to fix this issues?

**NOTE:** I've attached my whole code, even the layout main.xml, just in case someone else will later need the code, for the education and learning purpose :)

### GravitaijaActivity.java

```
package gravity.pack;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class GravitacijaActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    public float xPos = 50.0f, yPos = 50.0f;
    public float xAcc = 0.0f, yAcc = 0.0f;
    public int radius = 30;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
        main.addView(new Zoga(this, xPos, yPos, radius));
}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorArg) {
    if (sensorArg.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION)
    {
            xAcc = sensorArg.values[1];
            yAcc = sensorArg.values[2];
        updateZoga();

    }

}

public void updateZoga()
{
    xPos += xAcc;
    yPos += yAcc;
    FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    main.removeAllViews();
    main.addView(new Zoga(this, xPos, yPos, radius));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

  }         
}
```

### Zoga.java

```
package gravity.pack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Zoga extends View{
    private final float x;
    private final float y;
    private final float r;
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint (Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    public Zoga(Context context, float x, float y, float r) {
        super(context);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
    } 
}
```

### Layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF66FF33" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a mistake. You are adding value of acceleration into value of position. Instead of this you should keep adding the value of acceleration, through this you will get te value of velocity. Now if you keep adding the value of velocity you will get value of position. Now you should add this value of position into function updateZoga

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in onSensorChange code to move the ball in the screen. With the example in my case the ball don´t move correctly and for that I did the changes. This example Works fine for my.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent)
{
    //Try synchronize the events
    synchronized(this){
    //For each sensor
    switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD: //Magnetic sensor to know when the screen is landscape or portrait
        //Save values to calculate the orientation
        mMagneticValues = sensorEvent.values.clone();
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER://Accelerometer to move the ball
        if (bOrientacion==true){//Landscape
            //Positive values to move on x
            if (sensorEvent.values[1]>0){
                //In margenMax I save the margin of the screen this value depends of the screen where we run the application. With this the ball not disapears of the screen
                if (x<=margenMaxX){
                    //We plus in x to move the ball
                    x = x + (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1], 2);
                }
            }
            else{
                //Move the ball to the other side
                if (x>=margenMinX){
                    x = x - (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1], 2);
                }
            }
            //Same in y
            if (sensorEvent.values[0]>0){
                if (y<=margenMaxY){
                    y = y + (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[0], 2);
                }
            }
            else{
                if (y>=margenMinY){
                    y = y - (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[0], 2);
                }
            }
        }
        else{//Portrait
            //Eje X
            if (sensorEvent.values[0]<0){
                if (x<=margenMaxX){
                    x = x + (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[0], 2);
                }
            }
            else{
                if (x>=margenMinX){
                    x = x - (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[0], 2);
                }
            }
            //Eje Y
            if (sensorEvent.values[1]>0){
                if (y<=margenMaxY){
                    y = y + (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1], 2);
                }
            }
            else{
                if (y>=margenMinY){
                    y = y - (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1], 2);
                }
            }

        }
        //Save the values to calculate the orientation
        mAccelerometerValues = sensorEvent.values.clone();
        break;  
    case Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR:  //Rotation sensor
        //With this value I do the ball bigger or smaller
        if (sensorEvent.values[1]>0){
            z=z+ (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1]+1, 2);
        }
        else{
            z=z- (int) Math.pow(sensorEvent.values[1]+1, 2);                    
        }

    default:
        break;
    }
    //Screen Orientation
    if (mMagneticValues != null && mAccelerometerValues != null) {
        float[] R = new float[16];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, mAccelerometerValues, mMagneticValues);
        float[] orientation = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
        //if x have positives values the screen orientation is landscape in other case is portrait
        if (orientation[0]>0){//LandScape
            //Here I change the margins of the screen for the ball not disapear
            bOrientacion=true;
            margenMaxX=1200;
            margenMinX=0;
            margenMaxY=500;
            margenMinY=0;
        }
        else{//Portrait
            bOrientacion=false;
            margenMaxX=600;
            margenMinX=0;
            margenMaxY=1000;
            margenMinY=0;
        }

    }
    }
}
```

The view class where I draw the ball

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View
{
    static final int width = 50;
    static final int height = 50;
    //Constructor de la figura
    public CustomDrawableView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }
    //Dibujamos la figura
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        //Actividad_Principal x,y,z are variables from the main activity where I have the onSensorChange
        RectF oval = new RectF(Actividad_Principal.x+Actividad_Principal.z, Actividad_Principal.y+Actividad_Principal.z, Actividad_Principal.x + width, Actividad_Principal.y + height);             
        Paint p = new Paint(); 
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawOval(oval, p);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

}

That is all, I hope help us.